# Validate Route Parameter by Name across many endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0, attributerouting

In a .NET 6 MVC app, I have a lot of endpoints attributed similar to:

```
[HttpGet("getCustomerItem/{customerNumber:int}/{itemNumber:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomerItem([FromRoute] int customerNumber, [FromRoute] int itemNumber)
```

This is across several controllers, the main thing being the route parameter I'm concerned with is always called `customerNumber`.  I want to do some validation against that for each endpoint, to ensure the user has access to that customer.

Is there a way I can add middleware that checks if the endpoint has a route parameter called `customerNumber` and, if so, get the value coming in to validate it?  I think this is possible, but I cannot recall the correct terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this was easier than I was thinking it would be.  Turns out I could get the RouteData directly from the context.  Added this just before MVC in the pipeline -

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
     var customerNumberObject = ctx.GetRouteValue("customerNumber");

     if (customerNumberObject != null && int.TryParse(customerNumberObject.ToString(), out var customerNumber))
     {
        if (/* failed validation */)
        {
            ctx.Response.Redirect("/error");
        }
     }

    await next();
});
```